# Write Strings to Android data

Tags: android, arrays, string, internal-storage

i have a little problem, my small programm scan cards, i have Activity **AddNewCardActivity** where i call **CaptureActivity** and in  onActivityResult i have two strings :

```
card = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
cardformat = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
```

also i have Button **Save card** and String **CardName**( where is the name from ediTtext ) in this activity. Now in method onClick i need to save this strings to Android data.

Also when card is saved ,and i need to save another card to Android data , but it dont need to rewride my saved strings , it must save to new strings.

As i understand ArrayList is dynamically extensible, so i can us it, but i dont know how.

Or there is other ways to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

OK, i solved my little problem by using SQlite :)

Full tutorial i found by this link: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW5JdoFT0Rlt3ry5Mjp7s8cT